# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=971 (# cursors opened by this proc=971)

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, sqlite

> **android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=971 (# cursors opened by this proc=971)**

Hi I have a controller for querying the database. Code for getting data asynchronously, because I have more than 1000 records.

```
public void query(final Uri contentUri,
                  final String where,
                  final String[] selectionArgs,
                  final String sortOrder,
                  final int from,
                  final int limit,
                  final AdvancedQueryListener<Cursor> listener) {
    if (listener == null)
        return;
    if (null == SamsungApp.getAppContext())
        return;
    final ContentResolver mContentResolver = SamsungApp.getAppContext().getContentResolver();
    final Handler mHandler = Utility.instantiateHandler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) message.obj;
                    listener.onGetResult(cursor);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Runnable queryRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder sqlStatement = null;

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
                if (sqlStatement == null)
                    sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
                sqlStatement.append(sortOrder);
            }

            if (limit > 0) {
                if (sqlStatement == null)
                    sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
                sqlStatement.append(" LIMIT ");
                sqlStatement.append(limit);
            }

            if (from > 0) {
                if (sqlStatement == null)
                    sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
                sqlStatement.append(" OFFSET ");
                sqlStatement.append(from);
            }
            Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(contentUri, null, where, selectionArgs, sqlStatement.toString());
            Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(1);
            message.obj = cursor;
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    };

    FixedThreadPoolExecutor.execute(queryRunner);
}
```

> And I created a Fixed thread pool to handle all threads in my application. In that, I create Threadpool executor with max 100 concurrent tasks;

```
    FixedThreadPoolExecutor executor = getInstance();
    executor.mThreadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
```

> And My Content provider is given below

```
public boolean close() {
    if (this.isActive) {
        mAppDbHelper.removeConnection();
    }
    int count = mAppDbHelper.getCounter();
    if (count == 0) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            if (mSqldb.inTransaction()) mSqldb.endTransaction();
            if (mSqldb.isOpen()) mSqldb.close();
            mSqldb = null;
        }
    }
    return (count == 0);
}


public SQLiteDatabase open() {
    if (!this.isActive) {
        mAppDbHelper.addConnection();
    }
    if (mSqldb == null || !mSqldb.isOpen()) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            mSqldb = mAppDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }
    this.isActive = true;
    return mSqldb;
}

// 
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = open();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (db != null) {
        /* SQLiteQueryBuilder helps to construct queries that are more complex than
         * those supported by the SQLiteDatabase functions (for example, sub queries).
         */
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(uri.getLastPathSegment()); // Extract table name fromDeviceCursor uri
        cursor = queryBuilder.query(db,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder
        );
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        }
    } else {
        throw new DataLayerException(DEBUG_TAG + "SQLiteDatabase is null");
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

> And my problem is that every time If querying concurrently I got the issue

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                 Process: com.samsung.lighting, PID: 4949
                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:843)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:512)
                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.storage.repository.impl.WiSeGalleryRepositaryImpl.getNonSyncedIcon(WiSeGalleryRepositaryImpl.java:278)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.sync.OfflineSyncManager.syncAddedIcons(OfflineSyncManager.java:194)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.sync.OfflineSyncManager.startSyncing(OfflineSyncManager.java:164)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.sync.OfflineSyncManager.onFailure(OfflineSyncManager.java:737)
                                     at com.wise.cloud.group.WiSeCloudGroupManager$9.onFailure(WiSeCloudGroupManager.java:1603)
                                     at com.wise.cloud.queue.WiSeQueueManagement.addToQueue(WiSeQueueManagement.java:173)
                                     at com.wise.cloud.queue.WiSeQueueManagement.initialCheckInToQueueManagement(WiSeQueueManagement.java:117)
                                     at com.wise.cloud.group.WiSeCloudGroupManager.setLogicalGroupAssociations(WiSeCloudGroupManager.java:1662)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.cloud_interactor.CloudGroupManager.setGroupAssociations(CloudGroupManager.java:131)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.sync.OfflineSyncManager$7.onGetResult(OfflineSyncManager.java:391)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.sync.OfflineSyncManager$7.onGetResult(OfflineSyncManager.java:387)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.storage.repository.impl.WiSeGroupAssociationRepositoryImpl$1.onGetResult(WiSeGroupAssociationRepositoryImpl.java:344)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.storage.repository.impl.WiSeGroupAssociationRepositoryImpl$1.onGetResult(WiSeGroupAssociationRepositoryImpl.java:330)
                                     at com.samsung.lighting.storage.repository.SamsungContentResolver$1.handleMessage(SamsungContentResolver.java:73)
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Note** 
Everybody telling me to close the cursor `Cursor.close()` like

Everywhere in my application, I put in

```
try{
    //code 
}finally{
    if(null!=cursor)
        cursor.close
}
```

Help me to find out the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: close your `cursor` inside `handleMessage`

Comment: processing on the `cursor` is in another manager. If it is closed in here It will create too many problems.

Comment: so close it anywhere - basicaly you have too many open cursors

Comment: btw closing the cursor inside the listener method (`listener.onGetResult`) is not a good idea

Comment: and? did closing the cursor help?

Comment: @pskink when calling from multiple threads it is coming

Comment: what is coming? did you close your cursors (now you have 971 open cursors)?

Comment: after every data  read, I close the cursor, Confirmed

Comment: so why do you have 971 open cursors? the answer is: you did not close them

Comment: I dont know is that cursor is closed or not , But I wrote the code `cursor.close()`

Comment: ok so just for testing try `message.obj = new CW(cursor)` where `CW` is a custom `CursorWrapper` class with overridden `close` method - inside custom `close` method call `super` followed by `Log.d`

Comment: Actually, it is not the problem of opened cursors, It is the problem of threading.  And I created ThreadPool ,please suggest a good Threadpool

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: no, your problem is `android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=971 (# cursors opened by this proc=971)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153481/discussion-between-godwin-and-pskink).